# Creating Kits in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

we are looking for some advice / support.
We sell kits that are made up of many simple products.

We have 15 different sizes that we would like listed on 1 product page with the option of Black or White

Attribute 1 = Size
Attribute 2 = Color

Each of the sizes are made up of around 6-7 different simple products with different quantity depending on the size selected.

We would like if possible when the front end user orders one of these kits a list be produced of all the different simple products needed for this kit.

Comment: Try bundled products, I think it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out the [MageRevolution Package Product Type](http://www.magerevolution.com/mr/package-product-type). Although, I'm concerned about the fact that you want the kit to have an option of White or Black.

Magento can't deal with complex product types within complex product types. Therefore, you can have a configurable with package product types as associated products. However, if you're okay to show two kits as separate products: a White kit and a Black kit, then you could use the Package Product type to create the two kits, as long as all the associated products within the kit are simple products.